# Why is this simplification wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was simplifying an equation on khan academy and simplified:

(z-6)/(z+3)

(1-6)/(1+3) (because z/z=1/1)

-5/4

But got it wrong, the top equation is as simple as it gets. Can someone point out where my mistake is and also explain why it creates an asymmetry.

Comment: $\frac{z-6}{z+3}\neq\frac{z}{z}+\frac{-6}{3}$

Comment: You can "cancel" only common factors the denominator and numerator share.

Comment: You could do this: $\frac{z-6}{z+3}=\frac{z+3-6-3}{z+3}=\frac{z+3}{z+3}+\frac{-6-3}{z+3}$

Comment: It's true that $z/z = 1$ (if $z \neq 0$), but you don't have $z/z$ in your expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify a fraction by a *common factor* of the denominator and the numerator. Here, $z$ is a term of both the denominator and numerator but it is not a *factor*.

A simple example will convince you (I hope :o)):
$$\frac 25=\frac{1+2}{1+4}\neq \frac 24=\frac {2\times 1}{2\times 2}=\frac 12.$$

Answer (score 0):

When dividing the numerator and the denominator by $\frac{1}{z}$, you should arrive at the following result 
$$\frac{z-6}{z+3}= \frac{\frac{1}{z}(z-6)}{ \frac{1}{z} (z+3)}= \frac{1-\frac{6}{z}}{1+\frac{3}{z}} $$
I wouldn't call this a simplification, but I digress.